# Do the folder structures of minor version updates for Python conflict with each other?

Tags: python

I have Python 3.10.x on my system and have just updated to the latest version (3.11.xx). Do I need to remove the 3.10 folder or can it be left? Disc space is not an issue.

Have not tried to remove and there does not appear to be any current conflicts. However the Scripts folder in 3.10 has a lot of files that are not available in the 3.11 Scripts folder

UPDATE: It appears that the files in the Script folder relate to PyCharm

Comment: 3.10 and 3.11 are different versions and you can keep them there and  you dont need to copy or compare script foolder of two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to remove the old version. Be sure to check which one is present in the `System Environmental Variables > Path`, that's the one Windows will see and use.